# Yet another -> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As in title I have problem with microposts. I dont really know where is the error. Other posts about this error are not really fixing my issue nor giving idea how to fix it.

I am trying to display posts and display post create box.

Here is what I have:

**microposts_controller.rb**

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

      def create
        secure_post = params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
        @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(secure_post) 
        if @micropost.save
          flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
          redirect_to root_url
        else
          render 'static_pages/home'
        end
      end

      def destroy
      end
end
```

**microposts_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for (@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**memes.html.erb**

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <div class="row">
    <aside class="col-md-4">
      <section class="user_info">
        <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
      </section>
      <section class="micropost_form">
        <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
      </section>
    </aside>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**exact error:**
[localhost:3000/memes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3224.png)

I understand that there is NIL somewhere in the form - but where and how it should be fixed?

**rails server:**

```
    Started GET "/memes" for ::1 at 2015-12-07 22:46:48 +0000
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by StaticPagesController#memes as HTML
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 6]]
  Rendered shared/_user_info.html.erb (312.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_micropost_form.html.erb (3.5ms)
  Rendered static_pages/memes.html.erb within layouts/application (439.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 464ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty):
    1:  <%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
    2:       <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    3:       <div class="field">
    4:         <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
  app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__micropost_form_html_erb__1950492356_78981080'
  app/views/static_pages/memes.html.erb:75:in `_app_views_static_pages_memes_html_erb___1961772234_79299460'


  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (42.1ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `@micropost` to `form_for` but you haven't defined it anywhere so its value is `nil`.

change your call to `form_for` like this:

```
<%= form_for(Micropost.new) do |f| %>
```

or even better, instantiate it in your controller's action:

```
def memes
  @micropost = Micropost.new
end
```

Comment: <%= form_for(Micropost.new) do |f| %> Worked second time I tired. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's the first line in your form according to your screenshot. There are a couple possibilites:

1. Simply removing the parentheses, or deleting the space between the parentheses and `form_for` might do the trick.

   ```
   <%= form_for @micropost do |f| %>
   ```

   or

   ```
   <%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
   ```

   The reason is that `form_for` is a method that takes arguments. The Ruby parser assumes you are not using the parentheses if it sees a space right after the method call, and it tries to compensate. The combination of space and then parentheses may be throwing it off.
2. The other possibility is that `@micropost` itself is `nil`. You could check that by using a debugger like `binding.pry` or `byebug` just above it, and checking it:

   ```
   <%- byebug %>
   <%= form_for (@micropost) do |f| %>
   ```

   If `@micropost` is `nil` or undefined, you'll need to define it in your controller's new action.

   ```
   def new
     @micropost = Micropost.new
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Unfourtenetly I already tried that. I added Rails Server console log to main post, maybe it will give you some idea there...

Comment: Did you try checking the value of @micropost? If it's undefined, it will return nil, and you'd have to define it as @micropost = Micropost.new in your controller's new action.

Comment: I tried byebug but the site wont load after I insert that code to do it... Unless I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Nope, that means you're doing it right. When the site freezes, hop over to the terminal where your server is running, and you should see it frozen. You can type in it, and play with the code as it is at that moment where you added byebug, so type in @micropost, and see what it tells you. When you're done playing around, press ctrl+d (I think. You can also try typing exit. I use pry, and that works there)

Comment: ok, It told me its nil - no its not initialized anywhere. I tried to initialize it but it still didn't work.

Comment: Good, that solves your problem, on to all new problems! That probably means you're editing the wrong controller action. But in this case, you can set it in the form itself. Instead of @micropost, try Micropost.new.

Comment: Thanks for help - I got an answer already and its what you just posted - Micropost.new solves it

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to upvote the helpful answers, including your selected answer. That's the bit of cheese for us mice.

Comment: I have just 11 rep so I cant do it just yet :(

Comment: I see that now! I forgot to upvote your question, anyway, you should have it now. Welcome to stackoverflow!